# <a> tag breaks style when unwrapped

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements

me again, i have this script so that when the button "quadrant_1" that is on another html page is clicked it changes the button color on the first html page, but also **i want this to disable the a href link**, for that i have this:

```
        var noLink = $('a')
 if(localStorage.getItem('quadrant_1', ) === 'clicked'){
    $("#btn-institucional").css({backgroundColor: "#d8d8d6"});
   $("#btn-institucional").unwrap({noLink});

   }
```

To remove the  tag but the problem is that when th tag is removed it breaks all the row and buttons style

[before  tag is removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUWkD.png)

[After  Tag was removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYZNN.png)

This is one of the buttons html

```
<div class="number button col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="color:#ffffff; background-color:#003E8B; cursor: pointer; color: #ffffff;" id="btn-institucional">
            <a href="gobierno.html" >

            <p>1</p>

            <img src="icons/institucional.png" width= "50%">

            <p>Desarrollo Institucional para un Buen Gobierno</p>   


        </a></div>
```

Thank you so much for your help, i really don't know why this is happening if i have the div outside with the bootstrap class for the columns.

Comment: if(localStorage.getItem('quadrant_1', ) <-- why the comma?

Comment: So what is the HTML for this?

Comment: Where's the HTML?

Comment: i'm sorry i made a mistake in the formating and stackjoverflow didn't displayed it now it's on Thanks

Comment: So you should be unwrapping the link, not the div.... Or why don't you just remove the href from the anchor?

Comment: Thanks, how can i tell it to unwrap the link only i tried with href but it also breaks ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the style breaks because you're trying to `unwrap('a')` which removes the `<div>`.

You can try something like this:

```
 if(localStorage.getItem('quadrant_1', ) === 'clicked'){
   $("#btn-institucional").css({backgroundColor: "#d8d8d6"});
   $("#btn-institucional p").unwrap();
 }
```